# Cursor turns into resize mode when dragging mouse outside NSTrackingArea aligned with NSWindow borders

Tags: cocoa, mouseevent, appkit, mouse-cursor, nstrackingarea

I have a subclassed `NSView` that is aligned to the edges of the content area of the window, i.e. the view takes the whole area of the window.

Inside that custom `NSView` I install an `NSTrackingArea` also aligned with the edges of the view, to track mouse move and enter/exit events.

When I click mouse inside the view and drag outside the window, once the mouse intersects a window border, the cursor turns into resize shape (as if I was hovering over a window border) and remains in that shape, no matter where I drag - inside or far outside the window - until I release the mouse button.

I observe this bug also in many apps, even in Apple's own apps. In Safari for example, if you click on a background of a page and drag outside the window, the cursor sticks in resize mode.

The option flags of the `NSTrackingArea` don't seem to affect the bug. The bug only doesn't manifest if I don't add an `NSTrackingArea`.

This is really annoying, is there a workaround?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)updateTrackingAreas {
    if (_trackingArea != nil) {
        [self removeTrackingArea:_trackingArea];
    }
    NSRect trackingFrame = [self bounds];
    _trackingArea = [[NSTrackingArea alloc]
                     initWithRect:trackingFrame
                     options:(NSTrackingAreaOptions)(NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways)
                     owner:self
                     userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:_trackingArea];
}
```

Comment: Why would you drag the mouse? Have you tried `-[NSWindow trackEventsMatchingMask:timeout:mode:handler:]`?

Comment: The user may drag the mouse out for some reason. For example, when I click a button but then I realize that I don't want to click it, I can keep the mouse button down and move the cursor outside the button area and release it there. This will effectively cancel the button click. Your suggestion to start another run loop for this small task alone looks a little like an overkill, but for the lack of a better idea I will try it, thanks!